# Where to add a method for a model?

Tags: django

I have the following scenario and I'm wondering the about the best way to implement it within Django:

I have two models **Product** and **Person**. I want to give a **score** if a product is right for the person. My question is **not** about how to calculate this but where to do this within Django?

I've been thinking that I could have something like this…

```
Product.object.getscore(Person) 
Or 
Person.object.getscore(Product)
```

So how in models would I got about doing this (forget about the actual scoring, thats not the question)? but where to put this method and how in the model? I don't want to store score, it has to be dynamic based on the object passed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between product and person? 1-1, 1-M, M-M?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you want to calculate the scores over the entire queryset of either model, or as a property of an instance of either model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the method in either class in the following manner:

**NOTE:** My assumption here is that it's a 1-M relationship:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  person = ForeignKey(Person)
  ...
  def get_score(self):
    # do your thing here
    # use a person reference
    if self.person:
      # calculate score in one way
    else:
      # calculate score some other way 
    return score
```

OR you could implement it in the `Person` class. It all depends on whether you want to work from the Person's perspective or from the Product's perspective

What you are proposing with `Product.objects.get_score()` is for when you are performing the calculation over the entire queryset as opposed to a single item.

**UPDATE: After clarification that product is not related to Person**

In that case you can simply implement it as

```
class Product(models.Model):
  ...

  def get_score(self, person):
    # check the conditions you need to calculate the score
    if person.has_some_property and self.has_some_product_property:
      # calculate score in one way
    else:
      # calculate score some other way 
    return score
```

using the product instance you could then simply do:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=<some_id>)
product = Product.objects.get(pk=<some_id>)
product.get_score(person)
```

Comment: Product is not related to Person. What I want to do is just take the person object into product and do a simple calculate. the calculation is based on the type of person and the type of product. i.e. if person has x and self has x give y

Comment: and then the other way around is product has x and self has x give y